# No results for the web-scrapping from autoscout24

Tags: html, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, while-loop

I have a code to retreive data from autoscout24.com for my thesis which I will be working on used car analytics. However, I cannot retreive data and loops do not end. I do not understand the reason behind it. Can anyone help me? Here is the code.

```
brand = \[\]
model = \[\]
price = \[\]
total = \[\]
a = 101
k = 100
l = 20000 # calculates between € 0 - € 2.000.000
j = 1
while j \<= l:
    i = 1
    website = 'https://www.autoscout24.com/lst?sort=price&desc=0&cy=NL&atype=C&ustate=N%2CU&damaged_listing=exclude&powertype=kw&pricefrom=' + str(a) + '&priceto=' + str(a+k-1) + '&search_id=2gfy6suaasl&page='
    a = a + k
    j = j + 1  
    while i <= 20:
        website = website + str(i)
        response = requests.get(website)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'ListItem_wrapper__J_a_C'})
        i = i + 1
        for result in results:
            brand.append(result.find('h2').get_text())
            model.append(result.find('span', {'class':'ListItem_version__jNjur'}).get_text())
            price.append(result.find('p', {'class':'Price_price__WZayw'}).get_text().strip())
            total.append(result.find('div', {'class':'VehicleDetailTable_container__mUUbY'}).get_text())
```

I used my computer, I used Google CoLab; however, I could not reach anything at all. If you do this manually, you can reach the data; but no results if you do it in a loop.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily,  what would also be a good practice for debugging. Throw away all the iterating parts and focus on what will be in response of a single request. Behavior you analyse from this would be a good detail to clarify or answer your question. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Would be great, thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.